# Allowing HTML for textarea in MVC for models outside site context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, xss, data-annotations

I have a description field on a domain model that I want to open up for allowing html.  When I submit the form I get the 'possibly dangerous request' yada.... which I expected but it's proving difficult to remedy with my current setup.

My view model has multiple objects like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ISomething Something { get; set; }
    public IAnotherThing Another { get; set; }
}
```

Where `ISomething` contains the description and the interface and class itself is defined in another project from the mvc site.

Although I'm sure I could just add the `ValidateInput(false)` attribute on the controller action, I don't necessarily want to open everything open...just this particular description.

Anyways, here comes `[AllowHtml]` which seemed like the answer, but it's defined in `System.Web.Mvc`. It pains me to add the reference to an external library but I went to bite the bullet and I'm not able to even add that reference since it's not in my available list even though it's in the same solution as the mvc4 application.

I can't help but imagine that others have been able to overcome this but I appear to have been bested. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using MetaDataType attribute to extend your model?

If your Model is a Partial class, you could do:

```
namespace YourModelsNamespace
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ISomethingMD))]
    public partial class ISomething
    {
    }

    public partial class ISomethingMD
    {
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Descriptin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This way you are "extending" the model, and setting the metadata for that particular property. This classes will be in your MVC project, so you will have more control over the model. This approach can be used to add display name attributes, and the other ones in DataAnnotations namespace.

Note that this class's namespace, should be the same as your Model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  To give some further information, my class that's defined in a separate module is already a partial class of one generated by EF.  My view model which contains the partial (again defined outside of the site) incorporates more than just the partial.  In order to use this suggestion I'd have to declare a third partial, one within the confines of the site. Although I'm sure this works, it's flags as a potential maintenance nightmare.  My idea solution is without adding any further classes; Thanks though!